# How to groupingBy collector to create a new field from the data?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have data which arrives as such (list of maps):

```
{
    “name”: “Hello”,
    "source": “One”,
    "status": “Good”,
    “date”: "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM"
},
{
    “name”: “Hello”,
    "source": “Two”,
    "status": “Good”,
    “date”: "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM"
},
{
    “name”: “Goodbye”,
    "source": “Three”,
    "status": “Bad”,
    “date”: "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM"
},
{
    “name”: “Goodbye”,
    "source": “Four”,
    "status": “Bad”,
    “date”: "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM"
}
```

So I want to group this data by “name”, but also create a new field which collects the “source” and “status” fields into a list of objects. This would mean I'd have to map the inner data to a Java class as well (call these individual objects “sourceStatus” which I've already created a class for).

```
{
    “name”: “Hello”,
    “sourceStatuses”: [
        {
            “source”: ”One”,
            “status”: ”Good”
        },
        {
            “source”: ”Two”,
            “status”: ”Good”
        }
    ],
    “status”: “Good”,
    “date”: "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM"
},
{
    “name”: “Goodbye”,
    “sourceStatuses”: [
        {
            “source”: ”Three”,
            “status”: ”Bad”
        },
        {
            “source”: ”Four”,
            “status”: ”Bad”
        }
    ],
    “status” : “Bad,
    “date”: "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM"
}
```

I understand the groupingBy part can be done fairly straightforwardly with Java's Collector (https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector), but I'm not sure how to achieve the resultant set for my use case, where I not only create a new field but am also collecting then mapping inner data to a class.

Edit: "date" and "status" are going to be the same for all items with the same "name".

Comment: Are you grouping the maps in `data` by three keys: `name`, `status`, `date`?

Comment: Actually I should have noted that "date" and "status" are going to be the same for all items with the same "name", so I'm not sure if grouping by all 3 is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I found no easy way to do it with just one grouping but here is a somewhat more complicated two stage solution.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(newData("Hello", "One", "Good", "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM"));
        data.add(newData("Hello", "Two", "Good", "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM"));
        data.add(newData("Goodbye", "Three", "Bad", "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM"));
        data.add(newData("Goodbye", "Four", "Bad", "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM"));

        Map<Key, List<SourceStatus>> collected = data.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        m -> new Key(m.get("name"), m.get("status"), m.get("date")),
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), m -> m.stream().map(e -> new SourceStatus(e.get("source"), e.get("status"))).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                ));

        List<CollectedData> finalCollection = collected.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new CollectedData(e.getKey().name, e.getValue(), e.getKey().status, e.getKey().date))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        finalCollection.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Map<String, String> newData(String name, String source, String status, String date) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name", name);
        map.put("source", source);
        map.put("status", status);
        map.put("date", date);
        return map;
    }

    private static class Key {
        private final String name;
        private final String status;
        private final String date;

        public Key(String name, String status, String date) {
            this.name = name;
            this.status = status;
            this.date = date;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Key key = (Key) o;
            return Objects.equals(name, key.name) && Objects.equals(status, key.status) && Objects.equals(date, key.date);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name, status, date);
        }
    }
}
```

Two more classes needed:

```
public class SourceStatus {
    private final String source;
    private final String status;

    public SourceStatus(String source, String status) {
        this.source = source;
        this.status = status;
    }
    // Getters, equals/hashCode and toString
}

public class CollectedData {
    private final String name;
    private final List<SourceStatus> sourceStatuses;
    private final String status;
    private final String date;

    public CollectedData(String name, List<SourceStatus> sourceStatuses, String status, String date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sourceStatuses = sourceStatuses;
        this.status = status;
        this.date = date;
    }
    // Getters, equals/hashCode and toString
}
```

Not my finest code...

Answer (score 0):

The key for the `groupingBy` collector should be another modifiable map without key `"source"` and the value should be a list of `SourceStatus` class, which can be collected using `Collectors.mapping` collector.

*Note*: `Map`'s are used to represent a key and a final result deliberately.

Let's assume, `SourceStatus` has a custom constructor using Map<String, Object> as an argument to use it in the `Collectors.mapping`:

```java
public class SourceStatus {
    private String source;
    private String status;

    public SourceStatus(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.source = (String) map.get("source");
        this.status = (String) map.get("status");
    }
}
```

Then the code to get the resulting set of maps is as follows:

```java
Set<Map<String, Object>> mapped = data
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        m -> {
            Map<String, Object> key = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            key.putAll(m);
            key.remove("source");
            return key;
        },
        Collectors.mapping(SourceStatus::new, Collectors.toList())
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> {
        e.getKey().put("sourceStatuses", e.getValue());
        return e.getKey(); 
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)); // maintain insertion order
// convert to json
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(mapped);
System.out.println(json);
```

Output:

```json
[ {
  "name" : "Hello",
  "date" : "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM",
  "status" : "Good",
  "sourceStatuses" : [ {
    "source" : "1",
    "status" : "Good"
  }, {
    "source" : "2",
    "status" : "Good"
  } ]
}, {
  "name" : "Bye",
  "date" : "01-05-2021 7:35:58 PM",
  "status" : "Bad",
  "sourceStatuses" : [ {
    "source" : "3",
    "status" : "Bad"
  }, {
    "source" : "4",
    "status" : "Bad"
  } ]
} ]
```